# Insert an element in a particular position in array without native function

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm practicing some algorithm challenges and I found my self in a trouble with one of them:
The main idea is to be able to insert an element in a particular position of an array but I don't want to use something like insert() or append() python native function. For that, I've declared an empty array with a fixed-length and as the first operation, loaded half of the elements from the total that my array allows me.

All of this is in a function that receives the array and the position I want to insert this element. To put it briefly, my function verifies if the count for elements loaded is lower than the array's total length and the position es valid, modify the length of the array to insert the new element.

I don't understand why I'm getting the response that I get. I can't figure out the way to solving.

Here below is my code:

```
def array_load(list_value, pos):
  element_loaded = 0
  array_length = len(list_value)
  
  while(element_loaded <= array_length - 4):
    print("Please enter a number: ")
    num = input()
    list_value[element_loaded] = num
    element_loaded += 1
    print(f'ELEMENT LOADED COUNT: {element_loaded}')

  if array_length > element_loaded and pos <= array_length - 1:
    print(f'Please enter a number for position: {pos}')
    extra_num = input()
    for i in range(pos, element_loaded):
      list_value[i+1] = list_value[i]
      list_value[pos] = extra_num
      element_loaded += 1

  print(list_value)

array_value = [''] * 6
array_load(array_value, 1)
```

The input required for this example is **324, 2, 5**. After that, I add an extra element (number 0) in position [1]

Here my array after load process:

```
['324', '2', '5', '', '', '']
```

Inserting the number "0" in position 1 I get:

```
['324', '0', '2', '2', '', '']
```

I expected to get:

```
['324', '0', '2', '5', '', '']
```

If I want to insert "0" in position [0] I expect to get the following:

```
['0', 324', '2', '5', '', '']
```

And so on

Comment: *"the response that I get"* - what is it? Please edit the question to include the expected result and the actual result. See [mcve].

Comment: There is! Sorry, I forgot it

Comment: Can you please either a) remove the various input queries from the code and replace them with function parameters, or b) provide the *precise* input required to reproduce your problem? Take a look at the [mcve] help page for details.

Comment: Mind that ``for i in range(pos, element_loaded): list_value[i+1] = list_value[i]`` preserves the ``i`` position *by overwriting the ``i+1`` position*, and only *then* tries to preserve the ``i+1`` position.

Comment: MisterMiyagi I already did it, Notice that I added my expected output. The numbers that I loaded was 324, 2, 5 and after that, I want to add 0 in position [0]

Comment: @Iván The point is that you are *much* more likely to find help if people can focus on solving your problem, not reproducing your problem.

Comment: Right @MisterMiyagi! But I don't follow you of what is missing in my question.

Comment: It would be a good idea just to write, after the code, that the input ``324``, ``2``, ``5``, ``0`` is required to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you insert numbers "in the middle". This loop:

```
for i in range(pos, element_loaded):
  list_value[i+1] = list_value[i]
  list_value[pos] = extra_num
  element_loaded += 1
```

will first overwrite index `pos + 1` with the value in `pos`. In the next iteration we take the value of `list_value[pos + 1]` and copy it to `list_value[pos + 2]`, etc.. In the end the entire subarray `list_value[pos + 1:]` will be filled with the value originally stored at `list_value[pos]`. Instead move the elements starting from the one with the highest index:

```
for i in range(element_loaded, pos, -1):
    list_value[i] = list_value[i - 1]

list_value[pos] = extra_num
element_loaded += 1
```

Also don't insert the new value and increment the counter in the loop. The insertion isn't needed to be done multiple times and incrementing the counter in the loop leads to an invalid state after the insertion is done.